# Is Ms Access DBMS Or RDBMS?

Tags: ms-access, rdbms, database

IS Ms Access DBMS or RDBMS?
I also do Google to find answer of this question,but in some website or blog says it is DBMS while others are says it is RDBMS..
so what is correct answer? and Please understand why it is DBMS or RDBMS?

Comment: Access is a user interface over JET/ACE. They're the database-y bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS Access is a `Relational Database Management System` so therefore `RDBMS`, however you can use it in a non-relational fashion if you so wish so it can be used as a `DBMS`.

Comment: @Matt_Donnan  according to Franck Edgar Code 12 rules (by the creator of RDBMS) Access is absolutly not a RDBMS. 1 - there is no system table / meta dictionnary in Access. 2 - There is no transaction in Access. 3 - sets operations are not possible beacuse Access use an iterative access to treats rows... and so on !

Comment: @SQLpro: Sorry, but that is incorrect: 1: `MSysObjects` and friends, 2: `DBEngine.BeginTrans()` (or the corresponding ADO statement, or the [BEGIN TRANSACTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/transaction-statement-microsoft-access-sql) SQL statement), 3: No idea what you mean here...

Comment: @Heinzi: no you are wrong. 1) Such table does not exists. It is a function that analyze the content of the file to find the tables. 2) this is not the way to do a transaction that need SQL command BEGIN TRANSACTION / COMMIT or ROLLBACK. Applicative transaction are not RDBMS transactions. 3) refer Codd rule 7 like the possibility to do an UPDATE on the PK values of the table.

Comment: @SQLpro: 1. That's interesting, I did not know that. Do you have a source for that? 2 and 3. I don't see anything in [the 12 rules](https://reldb.org/c/index.php/twelve-rules/) supporting your point of view. Anyway, MS Access (or more precisely, the JET/ACE Engine) is generally considered a RDBMS in the commonly used sense of the word (definitely not my RDBMS of choice, but an RDBMS nevertheless). If you want to write an answer with a thorough analysis of why the ACE engine does not satisfy Codd's definition, I'm sure that would be an interesting read (and get my upvote).

Comment: For part three, the demo I use for my engineering courses is the following one : CREATE TABLE T (C INT PRIMARY KEY); INSERT INTO T VALUES (1), (2), (3); UPDATE T SET C = C + 1; This works on every RDBMS except Access, PostGreSQL, MySQL... which are not real RDBMS and violate rule 7 of Codd's rules

Comment: For part 2, just read Codd's rule n°5 : **A relational system may support several languages [...] However, there must be at least one language [...] supporting all of the following items: [...] Transaction boundaries (begin, commit and rollback).**

Comment: @SQLpro: Nice example for point 3, thanks! Sorry if I'm a little slow today, I still don't get point 2: Access *does* support BEGIN TRASNSACTION/COMMIT and ROLLBACK

Comment: No : transactions are limited to one table at time in Access https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=how-to-access-transaction. Real RDBMS transaction must support many tables !

Comment: @SQLpro: Are you sure about that? I've been using table-spanning transactions in Access databases for decades. I also don't see that mentioned in the link.

Comment: @SQLpro: PS: I also have an answer written here on this question, and I've taken the liberty of incorporating the information about Codd's rules into it. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer**: Both.

**Detail**:

Microsoft Access is a DBMS but also something more: a **personal database system**. That is, a DBMS *plus* an application generator. While Microsoft Access contains a DBMS engine that creates, processes, and administers the database, it also contains form, report, and query components that are the Microsoft Access application generator.

**Source**:

Page 13

Database Processing: Fundamentals, Design, and Implementation

David M. Kroenke, David J. Auer

12th Edition

ISBN13: 9780132145374

Comment: Can you please give an explanation for what @nvogel has said?

Comment: While nothing is wrong here, it didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

First, we need to define DBMS and RDBMS. Let me quote the relevant part from [the Wikipedia page on Databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) (emphasis mine):

> Connolly and Begg define database management system (DBMS) as a "software system that enables users to define, create, maintain and control access to the database". **Examples of DBMS's include** MySQL, PostgreSQL, MSSQL, Oracle Database, and **Microsoft Access**.
>
> The DBMS acronym is sometimes extended to indicate the underlying database model, with **RDBMS for the relational**, OODBMS for the object (oriented) and ORDBMS for the object-relational **model**. Other extensions can indicate some other characteristic, such as DDBMS for a distributed database management systems.

<sup>(Yes, Wikipedia should not be used as a scientific source, but we are talking about basic definitions here.)</sup>

In other words, DBMS is the *general term* for all kinds of DBMS's, whereas RDBMS are those DBMS which use a relational database model.

---

Whether MS Access can be considered an RDBMS or not depends on how strict your definition of RDBMS is.

- In the most general sense, since MS Access uses the "classic" *field/table/foreign key* model of storing data, it's underlying database model is relational. Thus,

  - MS Access is an RDBMS. Since every RDBMS is an DBMS,
  - MS Access is also a DBMS.
- If we take a more strict definition of RDBMS, for example, ["Codd's twelve commandments"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules), the Access database engine (as well as many other DBMS typically marketed as "relational" in the more general sense of the term) does not satisfy all criteria listed there, and is therefore, *according to Codd's definition of RDBMS*, not considered a "real" RDBMS.

Comment: @SanmithaSadhishkumar: Yes, MySQL and Oracle are also RDBMS's.

Comment: Then u have included them as examples for DBMS? you are mentioning that "All RDBMS are DBMS" In that sense did u mention that?

Comment: @SanmithaSadhishkumar: Yes, all the DBMS examples in the quoted Wikipedia snippet are, coincidentally, also RDBMS. It might have been wise to add non-RDBMS examples as well, but, alas, I did not write that Wikipedia article.

Comment: Can you please give an explanation for what @nvogel has said?

Comment: And @Analytic Lunatic said?

Comment: @SanmithaSadhishkumar: I disagree with both of nvogel's points, I don't know why he thinks they are true: (a) Jet/ACE *is* relational, maybe he mixes it up with [JET Blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine), which is indeed an ISAM storage technology. (b) Just because the MS Access product consists of both a database engine and an application development tool doesn't make it *not* a database engine.

Comment: @SanmithaSadhishkumar: About Analytic Lunatic: He's right. His answer does not address the **R**DBMS part, though.

Comment: Could you please give some additional links to assure your point? Because I don't know about Jet/ACE or JET blue/ISAM even Ms Access. To be Frank, I couldn't understand some of the points said by you all. Sorry for that. I'm using MySQL and SQLite. So I know about RDBMS and DBMS. That's why I offered bounty. It's a humble request from my side. Could you be simple in your answer? Or explain with simple concepts? Please. If I ask a question Ms Access is a RDBMS or DBMS, then what would be your answer?

Comment: I know that RDBMS is an updated version of DBMS or a kind of DBMS. So shall I consider s access as rdbms alone? It automatically means that it is type of dbms. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. An RDBMS is a kind of DBMS, and Access is both.

Comment: Don't think that I didn't offer bounty to you. I am waiting for others to defend their points. :)

Comment: @Heinzi If you want to use the term DBMS for a UI that includes the ability to create tables then by that logic surely Azure Data Studio and even Microsoft Word would also qualify as DBMSs. Support for foreign keys doesn't make Jet/ACE relational. Jet/ACE is more like the SQL model than the relational model but I think it's pretty difficult to justify it as an implementation of either of those things.

Comment: @nvogel: Let's forget about the UI, let's talk about the database engine. I don't quite understand yet *why* you think Jet/ACE is non-relational (or non-SQL). To help me understand your point of view, can you give me an example of a feature that (1) is included in all the systems traditionally considered to be DBMSs (SQL Server, SQLite, MySql, etc.), but (2) is missing from Jet/ACE, thereby making it non-relational (or non-SQL)?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Access is an application development tool, not a DBMS or an RDBMS.

The Access application is bundled with (but distinct from) Jet/ACE, which is a system for sharing data over a filesystem or via ODBC. In principle that can include accessing relational or non-relational databases. Jet/ACE isn't "relational" though. It is based (very loosely) on the SQL model of data rather than the relational model but is more of an ISAM cursor-engine than any SQL DBMS.

Comment: Sanmitha asked me to comment on your answer, which I did in a comment on my answer. I'll repost it here to ping you and to give you the opportunity to defend your point of view: (a) Jet/ACE is relational, maybe you are mixing it up with [JET Blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine), which is indeed an ISAM storage technology? (b) Just because the MS Access product consists of both a database engine and an application development tool doesn't make it *not* a database engine.

Comment: (And yes, after working with both Jet and SQL Server for decades, I will agree that Jet/ACE is not a terribly good RDBMS, that some of its features focus more on rapid application development than on reliability and stability, and that I'm really glad that we stopped using it as a database backend a long time ago.)